# Is there any impact if dependency was duplicated in pom.xml

Tags: maven

in pom.xml file, I found that the below dependency was repeated twice. Is there any bad impact if a dependency was defined multiple timese? Thanks.

```js
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
<artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>batik</groupId>
<artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is not repeating, see the `<artifactId>`, if you really mean that you have duplicated dependencies, it doesn't harm but clean it up